# select columns based on row values of another dataset

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two dataframes *dfA* and *dfB*. I want to select several columns of *dfA* based on the rows in *dfB*. This is how my *dfA* looks like:

```
index    abandoned     dismiss     yes      train    tram    go  
0          0.5           9.1       1.4       2.5      2.5    5.6
1          2.4           3.2       1.8       4.9      9.3    3.2
2          1.5           5.7       3.9       2.1      1.1    0.9
```

and this is how *dfB* looks like:

```
index   keywords
0       abandoned
1       wanted
2       goes
3       train
4       bold
5       go
6       images
7       links
```

so I want my *dfC* looks like this:

```
index   abandoned   train    go
0        0.5         2.5     5.6
1        2.4         4.9     3.2 
2        1.5         2.1     0.9
```

This was my attempt, but it gave me null dataframe:

```
dfC= dfB[~dfB["keywords"].isin(dfA)]
```

can anyone help me? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with filter columns names by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
dfC = dfA.loc[:, dfA.columns.isin(dfB['keywords'])]
```

Or filtering by [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
dfC = dfA[dfA.columns.intersection(dfB['keywords'])]
```

---

```
print (dfC)
       abandoned  train   go
index                       
0            0.5    2.5  5.6
1            2.4    4.9  3.2
2            1.5    2.1  0.9
```